# Sigma notation but each result is stored in a new sequence of equal length (no adding)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

My background is Computer Science, so I recognise $\Sigma$ as a for loop that exclusively sums, returning one element/ answer.

What is the notation used to loop over a finite sequence, to perform any calculation, and store the output into a new sequence of equal length?

i.e. I don't want to add each iteration's answer together. One element should yield one unique answer.

---

All of your comments and answers have given me brilliant insight. I will still be working on this problem as good old fashioned practice. Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:measure-theory], [tag:loop-spaces], or [tag:abstract-algebra]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Abstract Algebra. I will change the tags now.

Comment: @StressedBoi: "Abstract Algebra" is about structures like groups, rings, and fields, not just "algebra that's more 'out there' than I'm familiar with". :)  ... Be that as it may ... One way to do what (I think) you want is, having defined your initial sequences as $a_0$, $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$, to express your second sequence as $\left(\;f(a_k)\;\right)_{k=0}^n$ (that is, "the sequence whose $k$-th term is the result of applying operation $f$ to the $k$-th term of the initial sequence").

Comment: Interesting idea about indexing each of them, and declaring as a function. I've seen that various notation before but as I'm in my early days of writing math, so finding it hard to remember all of the possible tools.

Comment: @Blue Must a set of elements be 0-indexed? i.e. your '\a0'

Comment: @StressedBoi: You can index any way you like. In fact, you can associate items of a sequence with an "index set", say, $K$, that needn't be integers, or any kind of number at all. Then you can write your calculated sequences as $\left(\;f(a_k)\;\right)_{k\in K}$ . As you're just starting-out in mathematical exposition,  it would be helpful if you described *exactly* what you're trying to convey. That will open the doors for people to provide *specific* recommendations for how to convey it, without having to talk in vague notational generalities.

Answer (score 0):

## General Comment

Outside of a block of pseudocode describing an algorithm, mathematical notation is basically [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science))less. Rather than an [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) programming style which would have things like "for loops", mathematics is usually written like a [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) style. Because of this, the verb "store" (as in "store the output") doesn't really match up with any standard mathematical notation.

## Main Answer

If the operation only involves the current entry in the sequence, then variations of the the idea in [Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052218/sigma-notation-but-each-result-is-stored-in-a-new-sequence-of-equal-length-no-a#comment8369878_4052218) would be common. Define $f$ to be the function that outputs the "any calculation", and define something like $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ to be the initial entries of the sequence. Then the new sequence could be written like $\left(\;f(a_k)\;\right)_{k=0}^n$ or $\left\langle f\left(a_k\right)\right\rangle_{k}$, etc., depending on the author's personal style.

To answer [a follow-up comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052218/sigma-notation-but-each-result-is-stored-in-a-new-sequence-of-equal-length-no-a#comment8369986_4052218), the sequence can be indexed in whatever way suits your needs in context. For example $a_7,a_8,a_9$ and $\left(\;f\left(a_k\right)\;\right)_{k=7}^9$ would be fine. If the original sequence is a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of some sequence discussed earlier, you could even write things like $\left\langle f\left(a_{k^2-k}\right)\right\rangle_{k=1}^{17}$. In practice, you often might not have need to bundle the sequence together like this, and might just write things like "Let $b_n=f(a_n)$ for all $n\in\left\{7,\ldots,93\right\}$."

Also, this notation has no trouble with infinite sequences. For example:

> Define $b_n$ to be $n!$ (the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)), and define $f(k)=k^3$. Then define $c_n=f(b_n)$ for all $n$. Note that the infinite sequence $\left\langle c_n\right\rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ grows even faster than the $a_n$ do.

## Sums

As mentioned before, mathematics isn't really written in an imperative way. So mathematical sums with $\sum$ are not best thought of as a for loop. Instead, I would say that the approach in mathematics is often similar to [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). With that in mind, $\sum$ is probably most analogous to a [fold/reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) with the addition operation and $0$ as the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

${\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{1000}} 2i$ could correspond to things like `foldr (+) 0 [2*i | i<-[1..10^3]]` in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFIS0/J6VIQUNbU8FAIdpIK1OhRiFTwUZXIdpQT8/QIM44Nvb/fwA)). In [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), the equivalent (inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366417/1818245)) would be `reduce(add, [2*i for i in range(1,10**3+1)], 0)` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco9DoQgEEDh3lNMCUgBehxjQQR2SXSGjGPh6fFns@37Xj3lSzi2lpk2yAcuQrTuULZKLMApHkvqXqSaOAjx30KMXeWCon6XuoOFaTAF8nNBQeCAn6S89c6Ysfd6tuC0bu0C)) using the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) modules (and ignoring the existence of [`sum`](https://tio.run/##Nco9DoQgEEDh3lNMCUgBehxjQQR2SXSGjGPh6fFns@37Xj3lSzi2lpk2yAcuQrTuULZKLMApHkvqXqSaOAjx30KMXeWCon6XuoOFaTAF8nNBQeCAn6S89c6Ysfd6tuC0bu0C)).

Answer (score 0):

The sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a[k]$ over a length-$n$ iterable (let's say an array) $a$ can be achieved in Python as `functools.reduce(operator.add, a)`. Your question is effectively how a mathematician would denote `functools.reduce(f, a)` for an arbitrary binary function $f$ (unless you only care about how it's said in programming instead, in which case I've already answered that, albeit somewhat stepping on @MarkS.'s toes in doing so).

**I don't think there is a general notation.** Some special cases have an equivalent of $\sum$, such as $\prod$ for multiplication, $\bigcup$ ($\bigcap$) for sets' unions (intersections), and so on. The best option would be to explicitly define something analogous to partial sums. So let's define *partial calculations* $C_n$ by$$C_1:=a_0,\,C_{k+1}:=f(C_k,\,a_k)$$(forgive the $+1$s; they result from me using Python, which is $0$-indexed, in the above example, but then many (most?) programming languages are $0$-indexed). In practice, you'd have to present this definition to your readers.

The sum I gave in Python could be written as `functools.reduce(operator.add, a, 0)`. This allows a length-$0$ choice of `a` to be supported. The equivalent for multiplication is `functools.reduce(operator.mul, a, 1)`. The extra argument checks because $0+x=1\times x=x$. General $f$ won't have a left-identity, which is why I started with $C_1$ rather than $C_0$, which would have to be the left-identity. (We call $0$ an empty sum; we call $1$ an empty product.)